# What is the JSON format pattern for this DateTime?

Tags: java, spring, datetime

What is the JsonFormat Pattern for this Datetime String?

```
"2021-02-16Z09:38:35"
```

It has been defined as a STRING (ISO DATETIME FORMAT).

I have defined it as -

```
@JsonProperty("lastDT")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'Z'HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private ZonedDateTime lastDT;
```

I keep receiving a JSON Parsing error

```
Failed to deserialize java.time.ZonedDateTime: (java.time.DateTimeException) Unable to obtain 
ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2021-02-16T09:38:35 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ISO 8601 format, botched

You asked:

> What is the JsonFormat Pattern for this Datetime String?
>
> `"2021-02-16Z09:38:35"`

Looks like somebody tried for a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format but failed.

In ISO 8601, there should be a `T` between the date portion and time-of-day portion of a string.

Correct format would be `2021-02-16T09:38:35` rather than `2021-02-16Z09:38:35` with a `T`, not `Z`.

I suggest you educate the publisher of your data feed about correct usage of ISO 8601.

## Use `LocalDateTime`, not `ZonedDateTime`

A string like `2021-02-16T09:38:35` indicates a date and a time but lacks any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So you should change your code to use `LocalDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime`.

```
String inputCorrected = "2021-02-16Z09:38:35".replace( "Z" , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( inputCorrected ) ;
```

## Zulu time

A `Z` is used in ISO 8601 to indicate an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. The letter is pronounced “Zulu” per aviation/military tradition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;    // Represent a moment as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2021-02-16T09:38:35Z

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Basil, much appreciated. I will keep that in mind for any future implementations